# How to read lines of a file to be lists instead of strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

I have a file where each line is a list representation of a tree. For example, one of these lines in the file is:

```
[1, [[2,[]], [3, [ [5,[]], [6, [ [10,[]] ] ] ]], [4, [ [7,[]], [8,[]], [9,[]] ]] ]]
```

If I copy and paste this into my program, it understands that it is a list and I can easily manipulate it to find the root and the children, and then take those children and find their children, etc. When I read a file line by line, it takes those lines and turns them into strings. If I try to convert these strings into lists then it takes each individual character in the string to be a different item in the list and thats not what I want.

I just want to know how I can read a file line by line but instead of it spitting out strings, it gives me each line in its literal list form. The file I'm reading is a .txt file and it must stay this way I cant save it as a .py file or anything like that.

Comment: Have you heard of the `pickle` or `csv` modules?

Comment: You are looking for [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `ast` module:

```
>>> s = "[1, [[2,[]], [3, [ [5,[]], [6, [ [10,[]] ] ] ]], [4, [ [7,[]], [8,[]], [9,[]] ]] ]]"
>>> l = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> l[0]
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load a datafile into a list like this and the types will be handled correctly:

```
def load_lines():
    res=[]
    with open("datafile.txt","r+") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            a_line = [ast.literal_eval(text) for text in line.split(',')]
            res.append(a_line)
    return res
```